# Removing primary y-axis labels and ticks while keep labels and ticks of secondary y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to remove primary y-axis labels and ticks while keeping labels and ticks of the secondary y-axis. I have used the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Dependent, Sig_pair_count)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = Dependent, y = Sig_pair_count, alpha = 0.3, width=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Dependent, y = value*2.5, colour = name)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./2.5, name="Reflectance")) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) + xlab("Wavelength") + ylab("") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        text = element_text(family = "serif", color = "black", size = 15),
        axis.text = element_text(family = "serif", color = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

which returns me

[image: ![enter image description here]

You can see that though the variable of primary y-axis has values 0 and 1, the plot shows 0-2. How can I have the values between 0-1 and have the plot like this

[image]
Data

```
data = structure(list(Dependent = 350:1799, Sig_pair_count = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PUSA44 = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.16, 0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.18, 0.19, 0.19, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.21, 0.21, 0.22, 0.22, 0.23, 0.23, 0.24, 0.24, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.26, 0.26, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 
0.29, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 
0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 
0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 
0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 
0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 
0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 
0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 
0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 
0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 
0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 
0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 
0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 
0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 
0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 
0.28, 0.28, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 
0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 
0.23, 0.23, 0.23, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 
0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.11, 
0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 
0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 
0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 
0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 
0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.18, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
0.17, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 
0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 
0.16, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15), PB6 = c(0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 
0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 
0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.11, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.15, 0.16, 
0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.29, 0.3, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34, 0.35, 0.35, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.37, 
0.37, 0.37, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 
0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 
0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 
0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 
0.37, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 
0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 
0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 
0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 
0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 
0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 
0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 
0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 
0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 
0.38, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 
0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 
0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 
0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 
0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 
0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 
0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 
0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 
0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 
0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 
0.33, 0.33, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 
0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 
0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 
0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 
0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 
0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 
0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 
0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.21, 0.21, 
0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 
0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 
0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 
0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 
0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 
0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 
0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 
0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 
0.21, 0.21, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.19, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1450L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I get it there is no need for secondary axis. Simply map `value` on `y`, position the y-axis on the right and set the limits of the yaxis to the desired range via `coord_cartesian`. Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Dependent, Sig_pair_count)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = Dependent, y = Sig_pair_count, alpha = 0.3, width=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Dependent, y = value, colour = name)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Reflectance", position = "right") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.5)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) + 
  xlab("Wavelength") + 
  ylab("") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        text = element_text(family = "serif", color = "black", size = 15),
        axis.text = element_text(family = "serif", color = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: width
#> Warning: Removed 162 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

[image]